How to get exaclty value of function getItem() in antd?
I have 2 files:
data.ts:

const items: MenuProps['items'] = [

    getItem('Trang chủ', '/'),
    getItem('Kho tài nguyên', '/warehouse'),
    getItem('Khách cần mua gấp', '/feeds/urgently'),

    getItem('Tin hoạt động', 'sub1', null, [
        getItem('Thông báo vụ chốt', '5'),
        getItem('Công ty', '6'),
        getItem('Phòng', '7'),
        getItem('Nhóm', '8'),
    ]),

    getItem('Quy định và hướng dẫn', '/chat'),


];


and
sidebar.tsx:
import items from "./data";

const SideBar = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const translatedItems = useMemo(() => {
    return items!.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      label: t(item!.label),
    }));
  }, [items, t]);

  return (
    <>
        <Menu
          onClick={(items) => router.push(items.key)}
          style={{ width: 250, height: "100vh" }}
          defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
          defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]}
          mode="inline"
          id="srollbar-sidebar"
          items={translatedItems}
          className="p-2 font-medium overscroll-contain scrollbar overflow-y-auto "
        />
    </>
  );
};



How can I get the exact value of the items to put on the sidebar and among them there is elements that has sub-items?
I try this
import items from "./data";

const SideBar = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const translatedItems = useMemo(() => {
    return items!.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      label: t(item!.label),
    }));
  }, [items, t]);

  function getSubItems(items: MenuItem[]): MenuItem[] {
    const subItems: MenuItem[] = [];
    items.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.children) {
        subItems.push(...item.children);
      }
    });
    return subItems;
  }

  const subItems: MenuItem[] = getSubItems(items);

  const translatedSubItems = useMemo(() => {
    return subItems!.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      label: t(item!.label),
    }));
  }, [items, t]);

  return (
    <>
        <Menu
          onClick={(items) => router.push(items.key)}
          style={{ width: 250, height: "100vh" }}
          defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
          defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]}
          mode="inline"
          id="srollbar-sidebar"
          items={translatedItems}
          className="p-2 font-medium overscroll-contain scrollbar overflow-y-auto "
        />
    </>
  );
};

export default SideBar;


but output exacly wrong!
can u guys help me?
I tried some solutions like merging arrays or something like that but it didn't work
ps: i'm beginner so please excuse me if that's a stupid question!
